# Export server send status code 200 even if there's an exception

Tags: java, spring, highcharts

The highcharts export server returns HTTP status code 200 even when an exception is thrown during conversion, if we make changes to the exception handler (just like the one below) then an appropriate code can be sent back depending on the exception.

```
@ExceptionHandler(IOException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ModelAndView handleIOException(Exception ex, HttpServletResponse response) {    
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("error");
    modelAndView.addObject("message", ex.getMessage());
    response.setStatus(500);
    return modelAndView;    
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question here? How to make it return something other than 200?

Comment: and what is going wrong, the exception handler is not trigered? can you post your spring configuration, web.xml and logs/error messages. If there is a stacktrace can you post the full stracktrace

Comment: I do not have a question, exception handling in export server is not right. I have suggested some code changes which will make error handling better.

Comment: If you accept HttpServletResponse as a parameter in the exception handler and annotate the method with @ResponseBody then an appropriate HTTP error code can be sent when the conversion throws and exception.   It is not correct to return HTTP 200 OK even when the conversion goes haywire. I am making a suggestion to highcharts to incorporate this change.

Comment: This is much better served by posting to the github issues tracker: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues. Stackoverflow is general "help, how do I do X? I tried Y but it did not work."

Comment: Or just contact Highcharts support directly: http://www.highcharts.com/support/contact-email